# How can I see moved lines in a file comparison with vimdiff / diff?

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

Moved lines are frequently annotated as deletes and adds but they can be shown as moved-from and moved-to instead.

Like in this screenshot of Notepad++.

[image: Notepad++ diff'ing moved lines]

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you maybe demonstrate this with a small example?

Comment: If you're looking for alternatives to vimdiff & diff just search this site, it's been pretty well covered already: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diff

Comment: @Bernhard I posted a screen shot of Notepad++ feature of diff'ing moved lines. I'm looking for a cli alternative, preferably in vim.

Comment: @slm, I want to diff moved lines preferably in vim.

Comment: Wikipedia has a (short) [list of tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) that can do this. I have only used `meld` and it can't really detect moved lines (it kinda does) so take the list with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

For its diff view, Vim relies on the output of the `diff` tool, which consists of line insertions (`+`) and deletions (`-`), but no moves. For convenience, Vim is able to highlight changes within a line, but it does not detect moves of (blocks of) lines, unlike Notepad++. You would need to implement this kind of feature yourself (e.g. using the *sign column* to show the moves).

Comment: could you please elaborate in detail on that implementation in order to mark your answer?

Comment: You would need to get the changes (either by querying the Vim buffers for the lines highlighted in the `Diff...` highlight groups, or by running the `diff` tool yourself again, write a clever algorithm to detect the moves, and then use `:sign place` commands to attach the movement markers to the two diff buffers.

Comment: Alternatively, you could patch the Vim source code itself; getting at the diff information would be easier than in Vimscript. Such a patch (maybe using different colors rather than signs) could even be accepted into mainline Vim!

Comment: I rather hoped for a vimscript or a more feasible workaround. I leave it open for now.